# delphi I'd like to make EXE which doesn't have an icon resource

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm making many VCL form applications using delphiXE5 at present. The icon resource is unnecessary for it.

I'd like to make EXE which doesn't have an icon resource like a console application, but how should it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Open your `.dproj` file in Notepad or similar editor and delete tags

`<Icon_MainIcon>...</Icon_MainIcon>`

With this approach your project will still have version information, as well as runtime themes (or custom manifests) enabled.

If you wish to add icon back, just go to `Project Options -> Application` and load yours or use default icon.